# Who is allowed to write to an allocated address?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using VirtualAllocEx in Delphi to reserve memory in a foreign process like this:

```
var
 p : pointer;
begin
 p := VirtualAllocEx(Process, nil, SizeOf(Integer), MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
end;
```

The ProcessHandle has been opened with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` before.

After that my program writes a simple integer value to the allocated address like this:

```
WriteProcessMemory(Process, p, @MyInteger, SizeOf(Integer), BytesWritten);
```

Since the address is stored in `p` - I can save the address to use it for another application. The other application has to open the foreign process again to access/write the address in the foreign process.

My question is now: Who/What can read/write to this address in the foreign procces?

Is every process allowed to write?
Is every process allowed to read?
Do only have processes with admin rights the right to read/write?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem to solve, or is this just for learning?  `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory` are the correct solutions for very few problems.

Comment: There is something called a security architecture. there is a security descriptor related to a object. And that describes which have what privileges related to that object. When you creating a file,process, or handle (windows object), you have to specify a security descriptor for it. You could create a security descriptor using the microsoft security descriptor definition language and using the ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor API.

Comment: Only the process that called VirtualAllocEx can access the memory.  And the target process itself of course, although it could never find it without help.  Surely you are looking for a memory mapped file.

Comment: @Hans Are you sure? If that was so, it wouldn't be possible for an external process to use ReadProcessMemory on memory allocated by the target process. And yes, memory mapped file would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone with a process handle that grants read and write access can read or write the memory.  See:  [PROCESS_VM_READ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [PROCESS_VM_WRITE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  So, ultimately, it depends on how you got the handle to the process and the DACL on that process.

You typically get all access if you created the process or if you have SeDebugPrivilege enabled.  When you call [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you have to specify which kinds of access you want, it that request is checked against the security descriptor for the process.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, Windows would classify this as debugging.

You can debug your own processes, regardless.

You can debug another users' process(es) if you're granted (and enable) `SeDebugPrivilege`.

Note that granting SeDebugPrivilege to an account also basically makes that an administrator account -- i.e., if SeDebugPrivilege has been granted, somebody using that account can do essentially anything they want, and enable any other rights to themselves that they choose. Ergo: don't grant it unless you really need to (and unless you're doing something like debugging system service processes or something like that, you probably don't).

Comment: I don't think you need `SeDebugPrivilege`

Answer (score 1):

By default, anything with a compatible integrity level can use `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory`. That means an integrity level that is greater or equal to that of the target process.